# Даны числа N и K, вычислите количество правильных K-ичных чисел, состоящих из N цифр

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Как решить указанную задачу?

> Рассмотрим N-значные числа в системе счисления с основанием K. Будем
>   считать число правильным, если его K-ичная запись не содержит двух
>   подряд идущих нулей.
>
> Например:
>
> - 1010230 — правильное 7-значное число;
> - 1000198 не является правильным числом;
> - 0001235 — не 7-значное, а 4-значное число.
>
> Даны числа N и K, вычислите количество правильных K-ичных чисел,
>   состоящих из N цифр.
>
> Ограничения: 2 ≤ K ≤ 10; N ≥ 2; N + K ≤ 18.
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я сразу вопрос задам, вы только эту хотите решить или сразу в нормальной постановке (там 3 задачи только ограничениями отличаются). Эту задачу можете в лоб рекурсий попробовать, вроде бы именно под это решение ограничения.

Comment: Это одна задача

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишу сразу идею нормального решения (идея, т.к. считаю что задачи с тимуса самим водить надо). Нормального это значит сразу в полных ограничениях а не урезанные версии (которые кстати и должны подвести к этому решению).

1. Первая цифра нам по большому счёту совсем не нужна.
2. Нам по большому счёту все равно какая цифра, главное 0 это или нет.

Решение этой задачи - сгенериуем маску 0/не 0. (2 ^ 16 вариантов в худшем случае). Дальше для каждой маски нужно к ответу добавить 9^(число 1 не маске). Не забудьте что первый элемент в маске всегда 1.

3. Предположим мы расставили i цифр, для расстановки i+1 нам надо знать только значение i цифры, останые нам никак не мешают.

Решение более сложной задачи - динамика F[i][d] - число способов составить i первых цифр, чтобы последняя цифра была d (мы помним что нам важно только 0 там или нет). Пересчёт очевиден (с 0 только в 1 и k-1 способ, с 1 в 1 тоже k-1 и с 1 в 0 1 способ). База F[1][1] = K-1. Сложность O(N).

Дальше можно все это упаковать в формулу, вывести не сложно, формула сведется к быстрому возведению в степень и сложность падает до O( log N).

Comment: Нужна функция или функции

Comment: Задачи с тимуса сами кодьте. Идея у вас вся есть, если что-то непонятно спрашиваете а лучше код свой приведите, подскажу.

Comment: Я так понял что лучше всего самому изучать Искусство программирования.Спасибо